# Checking CustomErrors turned on in Code

Tags: c#, exception

Is it possible to check weather custom errors is turned on or off in the code on web application runtime.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I've figured out how to do it it's in...

HttpContext.Current.IsCustomErrorEnabled

Answer (score 3):

You can use [WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151456.aspx) to obtain the configuration for the website, then use that to get the custom errors block:

```
Configuration configuration =
    WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(null);

CustomErrorsSection customErrorsSection =
    configuration.GetSection("system.web/customErrors") as CustomErrorsSection;

Response.Write(customErrorsSection.Mode.ToString());
```

Comment: `OpenWebConfiguration(null)` doesn't seem to load the web.config in the current application but the web.config installed on the machine. Other answers show `OpenWebConfiguration("~")` but I haven't confirmed.

Answer (score 0):

OpenWebConfiguration(null) or HttpContext.Current.IsCustomErrorEnabled(true) gave me false information, this however worked great
Copy paste:

```
public static CustomErrorsMode GetRedirectMode()
{
    Configuration config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("/");

    return ((CustomErrorsSection)config.GetSection("system.web/customErrors")).Mode;
}
```