# Is there a way to check, programmatically, if an ASP.NET application's CustomErrors are set to Off?

Tags: asp.net

We usually catch unhandled exceptions in Global.asax, and then we redirect to a nice friendly error page. This is fine for the Live environment, but in our development environment we would like to check if CustomErrors are Off, and if so, just throw the ugly error.

Is there an easy way to check if CustomErrors are Off through code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Checking CustomErrors turned on in Code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367640/checking-customerrors-turned-on-in-code)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yep, the through [`WebConfigurationManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.webconfigurationmanager.aspx):

```
System.Configuration.Configuration configuration =
    System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("/");

System.Web.Configuration.CustomErrorsSection section =
    (CustomErrorsSection)configuration.GetSection("system.web/customErrors");
```

Once you have the section, you can check whether the mode is on or off as follows:

```
CustomErrorsMode mode = section.Mode;
if (mode == CustomErrorsMode.Off)
{
    // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 36):

I would suggest using the following property:

```
HttpContext.Current.IsCustomErrorEnabled
```

As mentioned [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/leftslipper/archive/2008/07/13/httpcontext-iscustomerrorenabled-one-of-asp-net-s-hidden-gems.aspx), IsCustomErrorEnabled takes more things like RemoteOnly into consideration:

> The IsCustomErrorEnabled property combines three values to tell you
>   whether custom errors are enabled for a particular request. This isn't
>   as simple as reading the web.config file to check the 
>   section. There's a bit more going on behind the scenes to truly
>   determine whether custom errors are enabled.
>
> The property looks at these three values:
>
> 1. The web.config's < deployment > section's retail property. This is a
>      useful property to set when deploying your application to a production
>      server. This overrides any other settings for custom errors.
> 2. The web.config's < customErrors > section's mode property. This setting
>      indicates whether custom errors are enabled at all, and if so whether
>      they are enabled only for remote requests.
> 3. The HttpRequest object's IsLocal property. If custom errors are enabled only for remote
>      requests, you need to know whether the request is from a remote
>      computer.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick...

```
using System.Web.Configuration;
using System.Configuration;

// pass application virtual directory name
Configuration configuration = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("/TestWebsite");
CustomErrorsSection section = (CustomErrorsSection)configuration.GetSection("system.web/customErrors");
CustomErrorsMode mode=section.Mode;
```